# Select all cells with xlwings Maybe with specialcells(xlcelltypelastcells)

Tags: python, excel

I would like to work through all cells of an excel spreadsheet using xlwings in Python. How can I do that?
I tried various ways of getting specialcells(xlcelltypelastcell) but was not able to get it to work. Does anyone know the right syntax for that in xlwings? Or know another way to get to all cells in a spreadsheet with xlwings?
Thanks,
Rob

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific what you are trying to achieve? For example, are you trying to loop through something like `Range('A1:Z100')` and then do what?

Comment: Now I want to compare two large spreadsheets with a relatively small number of differences between the spreadsheets. I want to compare the formalas cell by cell in each of the sheets of the excel files.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, what about the following:

```
>>> from xlwings import Workbook, Range
>>> import numpy as np

>>> wb1 = Workbook('/path/to/wb1.xlsx')
>>> formulas1 = Range('Sheet1', 'A1:Z100').formula

>>> wb2 = Workbook('/path/to/wb2.xlsx')
>>> formulas2 = Range('Sheet1', 'A1:Z100').formula

>>> np.array(formulas1) == np.array(formulas2)
array([[True, True, False, ...],
       [...],
       ....], dtype=bool)
```

If you have a contiguous Range of cells, you can also use someting like `Range('A1').table.formula`. Note that the `asarray` keyword is currently only working on the `value` property and not on `formula`, that's why the separate `np.array()`.

Comment: Hi Felix, thanks very much for your prompt replies and I apologize that I could not make the problem clear enough. The code that you present works fine as long as I know that there are not columns with content after column Z and no rows with content below row 100. The large Excel files that I am working with have more than 20 sheets with a variable number of rows and columns with content, sometimes the number of rows is > 25,000. So instead of "Range('Sheet1', 'A1:Z100').formula" I would like to  have something like "Range('Sheet1', 'A1:<lastcell>').formula".

Comment: The 'A1:Z100' was obviously just an example. If you hit timeouts for bigger Ranges then you have to divide the Range into chunks yourself for now - this might give you an idea here: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/77

Comment: The Excel API has something for that:
Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell) and I was hoping that xlwings may have a way to use that part of the API or some other solution to figure out where are the last row and column with content.

Comment: Yeah, `Range('A1').vertical`goes down until the last cell is hit, `Range('A1').horizontal` goes right and `Range('A1').table` does both at the same time: see the docs: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/datastructures.html#the-table-vertical-and-horizontal-properties

Comment: OK thanks! I am going to try that. I thought earlier that this gives dimensions of a table within a sheet and that it would not work well if the sheet includes several tables separated by empty cells.

Comment: Ok I see your point - `UsedRange` would probably work, too, but that hasn't been implemented yet. I've openend an issue though: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/112

Comment: Great, thanks very much! (I apologize that I can't up-vote your answer but I just got started on stackoverflow and haven't got enough 'reputations' for that yet.)